# Need help identifying vintage font

Tags: fonts

Can anybody tell me what this font is? Or something similar? I tried using whatthefont but nothing came up.

[image]

Comment: If you look at your Image the font name is already written at top right corner.

Answer (score 3):

Based on some research, I found this one, called 'Capitol' by Ralph M. Unger on Identifont.com that appears to be the same.

Looking up different "art deco" style fonts should provide you with some more similar results, but Capitol appears to be very similar. It also says "Capitol" up in the corner of your example picture, which helps to further the assumption.

[image]

Comment: If you look at the OP image the font name is already written at top right corner

Comment: Given that the OP provided no context for their image source, it is not readily obvious that "Capitol" is the font name. However, I did reference that fact in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**If you look at your Image the font name is already written at top right corner.**

[image]